# Как правильно разместить checkbox в Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

При создании окна чекбокс создается на изначальном окне, а не на вторичном, причем другие виджеты размещаются на нужном окне, можно ли как-то исправить?

код:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, END, Label, Button, Entry, Text, Checkbutton

class CreateWindow(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master

        self.start_button = Button(master, width=6, text="START", font="Consolas 10", bg="#22A5F1", fg="#fff", relief="flat",)
        self.start_button.pack()

        self.open_checkbox = Checkbutton(text="Открыть", onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
        self.open_checkbox.pack()

class MainWindow(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master

        self.create_button = Button(master, width=19, text="Create new", font="Consolas 10", bg="#191E2A", fg="#6EC7F4", relief="flat", command=self.create)
        self.create_button.pack()

    def create(self):
        root_create = tk.Toplevel()
        Frame = CreateWindow(root_create)

root = Tk()
Frame = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы элемент управления размещался в нужном окне, нужно первым параметром передавать родительское окно. В вашем коде для кнопок вы это делаете, а для `Checkbox` - нет.

Также, чтобы кнопки созданные у вас в классе `CreateWindow` (унаследованном от `Frame`) размещались в этом фрейме, нужно в родительский класс `CreateWindow` передавать `master`, а для дочерних элементов мастером указывать `self`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, END, Label, Button, Entry, Text, Checkbutton


class CreateWindow(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        # Кнопку крепим к фрейму (self), а не к самому окну
        # (иначе не понятно, зачем вообще наследовались от Frame):
        self.start_button = Button(self, width=6, text="START", font="Consolas 10", bg="#22A5F1", fg="#fff", relief="flat",)  
        self.start_button.pack()

        self.open_checkbox = Checkbutton(self, text="Открыть", onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
        self.open_checkbox.pack()


class MainWindow(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master

        # Кнопку крепим к фрейму (self), а не к самому окну:
        self.create_button = Button(self, width=19, text="Create new", font="Consolas 10", bg="#191E2A", fg="#6EC7F4", relief="flat", command=self.create)
        self.create_button.pack()

    def create(self):
        root_create = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        frame = CreateWindow(root_create)
        frame.pack()  # Не забываем фрейм разместить в окне


root = Tk()
frame = MainWindow(root)
frame.pack()  # не забываем фрейм размещать в окне
root.mainloop()
```

Также можно немного упростить, и `CreateWindow` сделать наследником `Toplevel`:

```
class CreateWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.start_button = Button(self, width=6, text="START", font="Consolas 10", bg="#22A5F1", fg="#fff", relief="flat",)  
        self.start_button.pack()

        self.open_checkbox = Checkbutton(self, text="Открыть", onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
        self.open_checkbox.pack()


class MainWindow(ttk.Frame):

    ...

    def create(self):
        child_window = CreateWindow(self.master)
```

Comment: Уже давно перестал думать что кто-то ответит на этот вопрос, но спасибо))